# Angular2 rc1 router navigate by url

Tags: angular, router

I have parent component with url /app
when I enter enter into that component, by default following component is loaded with following routes:

```
@Routes([
   { path: '/users', component: UserComponent },
   { path: '/other', component: OtherComponent }
])
```

and I am implementing OnInit interface:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigate(['users'], this.currSegment);
}
```

Since parent route is /app and child is implementing ngOnInit I can navigate to users, but if I want directly to navigate through url to route /other it is impossible.

Comment: which router are you using, `router` or `router-deprecated`

Comment: excuse me, I forgot to mention. it is `router`

Answer (score 6):

There are two methods availabel for the same

- `router.navigate(['.....'])`
- `router.navigateByUrl('.....')`

if your going to use first one than you can use like this

```
this.router.navigate(['/users']);
```

which accepts array with route name

and in second case you have to pass string as parameter like this

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/app/users');
```

> passing parameter

if you want to send routing parameter along with routing than you can use like this

this.router.navigateByUrl('/app/users/'+id);

where `id` is your data/key whatever

see also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#navigateByUrl-anchor

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your `@Route` params:

```
@Route([
  { path: '/users/:id', component: UsersComponent }
])
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    // assuming this.userId comes from somewhere
    this.router.navigate(['/users/', this.userId]);
  }
}
```

If you need to access your params, you can use `RouteSegment` in your constructor:

```
constructor(private segment: RouteSegment) {
  this.userId = segment.getParam('id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In angular2 rc1 there is no name parameter for routes any more, you now have to use the following code to navigate to a different page

`this._router.navigate(['/users']);`

Comment: How can I navigate to a sub-route like /users/:id with the navigate command?